# Route Not Found using createChildRouter

Tags: requirejs, durandal, single-page-application, hottowel, durandal-2.0

For my folder structure, i have (withing the Apps folder) views and viewmodels folders. I keep getting "route not found" when I try to click on one of the links.  Chrome also shows "route not found" when the page loads.  New to the childRouter.  Any ideas why I am getting "route not found?"

LVAvailabillity viewmodel-

```
 define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/system',  'knockout'], function (router, system, ko) {

var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
.makeRelative({
moduleId: 'viewmodels',
route: '',
fromParent: true
}).map([
   { route: 'AccessDenied', moduleId: 'AccessDenied', title: 'AccessDenied',                                                          type: 'intro', hash: '#AccessDenied', nav: true },
   { route: 'LCPost', moduleId: 'LCPost', title: 'LCPost', type: 'intro', hash: '#LCPost',     nav: true }
]).buildNavigationModel();

var vm = {
    router: childRouter,
    title: 'Letter Of Credit',
    introSamples: ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(childRouter.navigationModel(), function (route) {
            return route.type == 'intro';
        });
    }),
    detailedSamples: ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(childRouter.navigationModel(), function (route) {
            return route.type == 'detailed';
        });
    })
};
```

Comment: Are you using a `router` binding instead of a `compose` binding on the LVAvailabillity view? It might help to show your bindings as well. By the way, "Availability" only has one "l" at the end :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing component here was not using a splat route.  I changed the code as follows and it worked (only thing changed was adding the star *  )-

```
 var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
 .makeRelative({
 moduleId: 'viewmodels',
 route: '',
fromParent: true
}).map([
     { route: '*AccessDenied', moduleId: 'AccessDenied', title: 'AccessDenied',                                                          type: 'intro', hash: '#AccessDenied', nav: true },
     { route: '*LCPost', moduleId: 'LCPost', title: 'LCPost', type: 'intro', hash:   '#LCPost',     nav: true }
 ]).buildNavigationModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when setting up any router you have to supply a default route in order to avoid the Route Not Found  error message.

Try setting the route value of one of your child routes to ''.

route:''